# Dirichlet Problem

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

I have to solve the following Dirichlet Problem

$$\Delta u=0\quad\text{in}\,\,\, D,$$
$$u(\mathrm{e}^{it})=\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{e}^{it}+\mathrm{e}^{-it}),$$
 for $$u \in C^2(D)\cap C(\overline{D}).$$

Now should I calculate Laplacian of u than to equal it with zero or what should be first step?

Comment: The part of $u$ that you're given is defined only on a one-dimensional space, the unit circle, so it's hard to imagine computing its Laplacian. On the other hand, the $u$ you seek is defined on the whole disk, but you're already given that its Laplacian is to be $0$. So I don't understand what you mean by "calculate the Laplacian of $u$".

Comment: @AndreasBlass I just had it as an idea and I wanted to confirm that here. Otherwise I don't know how to start just any hint.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. If you translate the boundary condition in cartesian coordinates, then it looks like
$$
u(x,y)=x, \quad \text{whenever}\,\,x^2+y^2=1.
$$ 
Also note, that $u(x,y)=x$ is a harmonic function in $\mathbb R^2$.